# Create in WITH(CTE) using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create temporary table within WITH using function in PostgreSQL.

**Example**:

```
with mm
as
(
     select * from test
)
create table xyz as select * from mm
;
```

**Note**: Getting error near create

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
create table xyz as 

with mm
as
(
     select * from test
)
select * from mm 
where myfield = myvalue
;
```

Relevant [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html). In the documentation, there is no explicit description on how to use `create table as` together with CTE. However, it clearly states it's syntax (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
    AS query
```

Where query can be (quoting):

> A SELECT, TABLE, or VALUES command, or an EXECUTE command that runs a
> prepared SELECT, TABLE, or VALUES query.

From this it should be clear why your attempt failed.

Comment: According to you the "WHERE" should come after "select * from mm" right?

Comment: @Meen Yes, that is correct, I added simple where condition to my answer.

Comment: Yes! I got it. Thank you so much.