# CREATE TABLE with CTE statement

Tags: teradata

Is it possible to create a table from a query with a CTE statement?
Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE db1.test1 AS
(
  WITH cte1(v1) as
  ( SEL v1 FROM db1.table1 )

  SEL * FROM cte1

)
```

This is how the CTE's look like:

```
WITH employees(id, name, boss, senior_boss) AS
(
SEL
empls.id,
empls.name,
supervisors.name as boss,
senior_bosses.name as senior_boss

FROM empl_cte AS empls
LEFT JOIN empl_cte AS supervisors ON empls.boss_id = supervisors.id
LEFT JOIN empl_cte AS senior_bosses ON supervisors.boss_id = senior_bosses.id
),

WITH empl_cte(....) AS
(

SEL
id, 
name
boss_id

FROM all_employees
WHERE <some_filters>
)

SEL

*

FROM products
LEFT JOIN employees ON products.sales_rep_id = employees.id
```

Both

- converting the CTEs into views

and

- converting `employees` as a sub-query (`empl_cte` as a VIEW) in the left join

leads to a massive loss of performance (run time blowing up from a couple of minutes to days of work). I can't figure out how Teradata optimizer works.
`EXPLAIN` on the new refactored queries seem indicate that the `LEFT JOIN` becomes a product join draining countless of time.

Comment: Afaik no. There seems to be no workaround besides creating the table first and then `insert into test1 with ...`

Comment: Could you make your CTE into a view?  If so, then your create table statement will work.

Comment: @Nick I could but performance wise it is a disaster

Comment: Yes, left outer joins can absolutely kill a query.  Is it possible to use a Global Temporary table as opposed to needing a create table as select?

Comment: No, I can't use a GTT because the pipeline I am using does not support that.

Comment: Shall I open a new Q in order to ask help in refactoring my query and removing the CTE's using plain and simple left joins?

Answer (score 1):

This will work in V16 (and possibly earlier versions).

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        WITH x AS (
            SELECT ...
            FROM  ...
            WHERE  ...
            ) 
        SELECT  ...
        FROM x ...
        WHERE  ...
        ) D
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (PK)
;
```

Basically you need to wrap the whole query, including the CTE, in a SELECT with an alias.

Comment: No need to wrap the query. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24243963/4126114

Comment: @Shadi, the link you've posted is for a PostgreSQL question/answer, but this one is for Teradata.  Are you sure the answer in the link works for Teradata - I'm pretty sure I checked that version and it didn't, but I no longer have access to Teradata to confirm.

Comment: you're right. I missed the teradata tag.